# python, How to find specific key value in json file then save whole line of json file？

Tags: python, json, pandas, key

I am a newbie and I need to export specific key value in json file,I searched a lot of sites but couldn't find the code I need, hope this helps me

my json file

```
{"person":{"name":"Silva","sex":"female","age":21}}
{"person":{"name":"LANA","sex":"male","age":28}}
{"person":{"name":"Oliveira","sex":"female","age":35}}
{"person":{"name":"KENN","sex":"male","age":26}}
```

Need to export whole line json file where 'sex' is 'male' in JSON file

```
{"person":{"name":"LANA","sex":"male","age":28}}
{"person":{"name":"KENN","sex":"male","age":26}}
```

full code required

Comment: I don't know how to code, I'm new to it and I'm learning it

Comment: That is not valid JSON. What you have there is the string representation of four Python dictionaries. You need to open the file, read it line by line, evaluate each line (ast.literal_eval will help you), examine the resulting dictionary, test the 'sex' key and write your output somewhere

Comment: You have changed your data but that's still not a valid JSON file. Each line is now valid JSON but not the file as a whole

Comment: Yes, my JSON file format is like this, I am looking for code to fit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearing in mind that the input file is not a JSON file *per se*. Each line is valid JSON and therefore has to be dealt with separately.

For example:

```
import json

with open ('foonew.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out:
    with open('foo.txt', encoding='utf-8') as j:
        for line in j:
            if (d := json.loads(line))['person']['sex'] == 'male':
                print(json.dumps(d), file=out)
```

The output file will look like:

```
{"person": {"name": "LANA", "sex": "male", "age": 28}}
{"person": {"name": "KENN", "sex": "male", "age": 26}}
```

Alternatively, to get a separate file for each gender then:

```
import json
sexes = []
with open('foo.txt', encoding='utf-8') as j:
    for line in j:
        d = json.loads(line)
        sex = d['person']['sex']
        if sex in sexes:
            mode = 'a'
        else:
            sexes.append(sex)
            mode = 'w'
        with open(f'{sex}.txt', mode, encoding='utf-8') as out:
            print(json.dumps(d), file=out)
```

Comment: Also, how would I write the code if I needed to have the values in the "sex" key be saved categorically and named after what was in "sex"，@Olvin Roght

Comment: @jeriteri Not sure what you mean. Do you mean two different output files? One for male and one for female?

Comment: Yes, how does this modify the code? @Olvin Roght

Comment: What about `a+` mode? [...](https://tio.run/##dY2xDoIwFEV3vuLF5bURWVwICV9CGIht5Rnoa9oSMcZvr5RBXTzjTe457hFHtufa@ZRoduwj3ALb4k5xBHbaCjTMVVwjlqDthRXZa4tLNKcaJQwByDQFbBj2MJHVQPazZb4mc3gKBU27F6qJBxVEfkjZodN@G7HvMOgV@1cuHkrA4fivyz@NjPNko9jVapldEEqWYGjSLRuZ0hs)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Why a+ ? I never read the file and I always want to create a new version every time the program is run. What am I missing?

Comment: @JCaesar, you want to store entries in different files named after `['person']['sex']`, don't you? `open()` with `a+` mode either creates a new file or appends to existing which could shorten your code twice.

Comment: @OlvinRoght You miss my point. If the file already exists, I want to overwrite it

Answer (score 0):

You need to show what you have tried so that we can get an idea of the format you expect. Here is, however, one of the simplest way of tackling it -

I am assuming that you have a JSON file in which the details of all males and females are stored **(with each record separated by commas, and using only double-quotes `""` not single `''`! your given JSON file is not valid)**

From here you need to import json, then use json.load to convert to a python object (in this case it would be a list) and then iterate over it to check the key `'sex'` in each dictionary and filter accordingly. Full code:

```py
import json

filename = "<filename>.json"
with open(filename, "rt") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

new_data = []
for record in data:
    if record['person']['sex'] == 'male':
        new_data.append(record)

newfile = "<new_filename>.json"
with open(newfile, "wt") as file:
    json.dump(new_data, file)
```

---

For this code to work, the initial JSON file (`"<filename>.json"` above) should be of this format:

```json
[
  {"person":{"name":"Silva","sex":"female","age":21}},
  {"person":{"name":"LANA","sex":"male","age":28}},
  {"person":{"name":"Oliveira","sex":"female","age":35}},
  {"person":{"name":"KENN","sex":"male","age":26}}
]
```

---

PS: Kindly avoid asking for full solutions to homework questions on stack**overflow**. We have a lot of other work to do too.

Comment: This code will not work with the OP's data as shown

Comment: I know, hence I included the information saying "commas are necessary". However, if you found some other problem in the OP's data, do mention

Comment: Even after your edit that still won't work. Did you actually try it! JSON strings **must** be enclosed in double-quotes. Also, you shouldn't change the OP's data to [try to] suit your code.

Comment: i tried it, but it gives error。`raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 52)`

Comment: I noticed another issue in my answer itself. OP's file contains every person's data inside of the `"person"` key. corrected it

Comment: You have changed the OP's data to work with your code! That's patently wrong. If you're going to offer a solution in code then it must work with the OP's data as defined in the original question

Comment: @OlvinRoght i accept that. but as a human, it is also my responsibility to guide them towards structuring their json file right if found wrong. nothing is wrong in being human on SO, i hope? :D if no code would ever even work on the op's json file, isnt it our humane responsibility to suggest correction? :)

Comment: @jeriteri try it again, had missed out on one thing in my code.. and make sure this time the json file is structured correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import json
s = json.dumps([{'person':{'name':'Silva','sex':'female','age':21}},
{'person':{'name':'LANA','sex':'male','age':28}},
{'person':{'name':'Oliveira','sex':'female','age':35}},
{'person':{'name':'KENN','sex':'male','age':26}}])
```

If you have a json file, so:

```
s = 'file_path'

s = pd.read_json(s)
s = s['person'].apply(pd.Series)
s[s['sex']=='male']
```

Here, I convert the json to df then convert each row to separate columns and then filter the df.

Comment: But the OP has the given data in a file. You have changed the data to suit your code!

Comment: It is for demonstration. So just ignore the first part and read the json using the reminding.